# AJAX - 500 internal server error using same function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to use AJAX in my project to handle images (load more info and delete). Loading is working, but when i try to delete any of them, I recieve error 500 and php script is not used.

```
var page = 1;
var selected = [];
var mediaAll = [];
var jsont = JSON.stringify({"action": "loadMedia", "page": page});
AJAXcall(jsont, "loadMedia");

function AJAXcall(data, action){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(xhttp);
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      if(action=="loadMedia"){
        var media = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        mediaAll = [];
        mediaAll = mediaAll.concat(media);
        mediaLoaded();
      }else if(action=="loadMoreMedia"){
        var media = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        mediaAll = mediaAll.concat(media);
        mediaLoaded();
      }else if(action=="deleteMedia"){
        response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(response);
        page = 1;
        if(response == true){
          AJAXcall(jsont, "loadMedia");
        }
      }
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "./libs/img_handler.php", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send(data);
}
function deleteSingle(){   
   if(selected.length === 1){
    if (confirm('sure?')) {
      var dataS = {"action": "deleteMedia", "id": selected[0]};
      dataDel = JSON.stringify(dataS);
      AJAXcall(dataDel, "deleteMedia");
    }
   }
}
function loadMore(){
  page++;
  var jsont = JSON.stringify({"action": "loadMoreMedia", "page": page});
  AJAXcall(jsont, "loadMoreMedia");
}
```

When used function loadMore

> XMLHttpRequest { onreadystatechange: onreadystatechange(), readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, responseURL: "http://localhost:8888/project/libs/img_handler.php", status: 200, statusText: "OK", responseType: "", response: "..."}

When used function deleteSingle

> XMLHttpRequest { onreadystatechange: onreadystatechange()
>   , readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, responseURL: "http://localhost:8888/project/libs/img_handler.php", status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", responseType: "", response: "" }

Comment: Can you show us the server side code (PHP code) on `./libs/img_handler.php\`?

Comment: Best guess - there's something in the `deleteSingle` code that's killing the system... we'd need to see what that is.

Comment: you don't have to write var media = JSON.parse(this.responseText); for 3 times.

Answer (score -1):

You have mentioned that you have not used php script however responseURL seems referring to .php file.

Normally, 500 status code refers to Internal Server Error. Please try to check error log OR debug your code.

This will help you to get cause of error.